# google directions on maps api v 2 issue

Tags: eclipse, google-maps, directions

I had a question that I hope someone can answer. I am currently creating an app that will allow people to get directions. Now, my question is: I have to make a new class (activity) to add directions right? and for every service like distance matrix, and markers, etc. I didn't know if it was necessary. So, pretty much shortining what I am asking, for every new service, do I need to create a new class, or can I add it to a already existing class.

If anyone had a line of script that I could learn off of, that would be great. I am just slowly building my way up into this world.

So, in short, I need to put directions on my app. I already got google maps to work. Pretty much, right now, its just a map. There is nothing else to it. I need help adding directions. Thanks everyone who reads this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in adding a painted directions on the map, then you could follow this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps V2 for Android: Draw Driving Direction on Map](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

In the end of this post you will find a working project that you could use in order to understand how you could added it to your map.